# 413 Request Entity Too Large with Angular JS FormData

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, apache, xmlhttprequest

I am getting a `413 Request Entity Too Large` error when sending a serialized image in the body of a request along with other `POST` data using `FormData`.

Im running angular 1.6.0 on the front-end with PHP 5.x/Apache on the server.

The reason I am sending the file in the body like this is because I would like to give a user the option to edit some profile data and/or update their profile image simultaneously.

I am preparing and sending the request as follows:

```
$scope.sendRequest = function(){

    var data = {},
        header = {},
        file = $scope.file; // this is the base64 version of the image uploaded

    if(!empty(file)){ // user has uploaded an image

        data = new FormData();
        data.append('file', file);

        var user = $scope.user; // this is all other non-image form data
        for(var i in user){
            if(!empty(user[i])) data.append(i, $scope.user[i]);
        }

        header = { 
            transformRequest: angular.identity, 
            headers: {  
                "Content-Type" : undefined, // the is the only setting that works but I admit, its odd to set this to "undefined" - perhaps my issue is here?
                "Auth":session.token
            } 
        };

    } else { // user has not uploaded an image - standard form submit 

        data.user = $scope.user; 
        data.performer = $scope.performer;
        header = { headers:{"Auth":$localStorage.session.token} };
    }

    // send request
    $http.post($rootScope.API_ROOT+'/users/'+id, data.user, header).then(function(res){ 

        console.log(res.data);

    },function(err){ console.log(err); }); // "413 (Request Entity too Large)"

}
```

I have tried setting [LimitRequestBody](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#limitrequestbody) but this did not fix the issue.

I am able to upload images of similar or large size in other parts of my app where the image data is NOT serialized with the `POST` data, so I feel like I need to better configure my request.

Comment: Why do you `POST` a `base64` or `data URI` representation of `File` object and not `File` object?

Comment: this is the way I was able to upload an image using angular FormData. I am certain open to a more correct approach

Comment: Have you tried appending uploaded `File` object itself to `FormData` instance?

Comment: I think there's also limits on PHP configuration, can you try  `upload_max_filesize = 12000M;
 post_max_size = 24000M`, (inside /etc/php.ini)

Comment: @guest271314 I believe I am doing this with `data.append('file', file);`

Comment: @MichaelYin I do not have access to php.ini, only .htaccess

Comment: What do you mean by `base64` at `// this is the base64 version of the image uploaded`? `base64` is not `File` object.

Comment: :-( That would render it pretty hard. You might have to look into other solutions like uploading a file chunk-by-chunk.

Comment: `console.log(file);` will print the base64 representation of the image